# Finding the direction of an entire system using forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

I've been staring at this and trying different things for hours on end to no avail.

[image]

For the first part of this problem, I found the acceleration. I know F = ma

So Fnet/m = a

I got .252 for accel and it was right. So, I know my Fnet MUST be correct. It is 11.63N

The question says "Assuming the sled starts at rest, find the direction of the sled and child system in degrees north of east"

So are they talking about the direction the sled and child system is going **after friction force is taken into account, and the directions F1 and F2 are going? If so, isn't that just Fnet!?!?**

So under that assumption, I tried arctan(3.99/10.92) < Those are the Y and X components of my Fnet which was 11.63. My theta ended up being wrong. (20.1 degrees)

What am I doing wrong? Does it have something to do with the fact that the 30 degree angle they gave me is BELOW the horizontal?

**EDIT:** Figured it out. Apparently part b wanted me to DISREGARD friction force and only find the direction using F1 and F2 (why???) I'll leave this question up in case anyone could explain to me how Part b is asking for that... I interpret it as finding it WITH friction since it says "assuming the sled starts at rest"

Comment: The direction of friction is opposite the motion - so if you start from rest, the direction of the vector sum of $F_1$ and $F_2$ should be the direction of motion (adding a vector in the opposite direction will change the magnitude but not the direction).

Answer (score 1):

Friction wouldn't change the angle that the forces acted on.

It was stated in the question that it was acting directly opposite of the combined forces; which meant it was not changing the direction of $F_{net}$, just the magnitude.

It may have been a calculation error on your part.